# Unable to connect L2TP IPSec VPN from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, vpn, ipsec

I am trying to connect L2TP IPSec VPN connection from my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. Every time I am facing same error since the same credentials working properly to connect VPNs server from any windows system.

Can anyone guide me to resolve this issue?

Syslog:

```
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1492068318.2586] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="83adbec9-817f-4faf-9839-42eb41897c10" name="VPN connection 1" pid=2254 uid=1000 result="success"
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1492068318.2664] vpn-connection[0x1db45c0,83adbec9-817f-4faf-9839-42eb41897c10,"VPN connection 1",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 5561
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1492068318.2808] vpn-connection[0x1db45c0,83adbec9-817f-4faf-9839-42eb41897c10,"VPN connection 1",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1492068318.4059] vpn-connection[0x1db45c0,83adbec9-817f-4faf-9839-42eb41897c10,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: ** Message: Check port 1701
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: nm-l2tp[5561] <info>  ipsec enable flag: yes
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: ** Message: Check port 1701
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: nm-l2tp[5561] <info>  starting ipsec
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[IKE] destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA nm-ipsec-l2tp-4250[1] to 76.194.82.189
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 2 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 3 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 4 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 5 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: giving up after 5 retransmits
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: peer not responding, trying again (2/0)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA nm-ipsec-l2tp-4250[1] to 76.194.82.189
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 2 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 3 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 4 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 5 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: giving up after 5 retransmits
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: peer not responding, trying again (3/0)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA nm-ipsec-l2tp-4250[1] to 76.194.82.189
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 2 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 3 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 4 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 5 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: giving up after 5 retransmits
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: peer not responding, trying again (4/0)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA nm-ipsec-l2tp-4250[1] to 76.194.82.189
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 2 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 3 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 4 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending retransmit 5 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:18 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: Starting strongSwan 5.3.5 IPsec [starter]...
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: Loading config setup
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: Loading conn 'nm-ipsec-l2tp-5561'
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: found netkey IPsec stack
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.3.5, Linux 4.4.0-72-generic, x86_64)
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon test-vectors aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md4 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 08[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'nm-ipsec-l2tp-5561'
Apr 13 12:55:20 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 08[CFG] added configuration 'nm-ipsec-l2tp-5561'
Apr 13 12:55:21 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 10[CFG] rereading secrets
Apr 13 12:55:21 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 10[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Apr 13 12:55:21 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 10[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Apr 13 12:55:21 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: nm-l2tp[5561] <info>  Spawned ipsec up script with PID 5634.
Apr 13 12:55:21 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 11[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'nm-ipsec-l2tp-5561'
Apr 13 12:55:21 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 13[IKE] initiating Main Mode IKE_SA nm-ipsec-l2tp-5561[1] to 76.194.82.189
Apr 13 12:55:21 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 13[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Apr 13 12:55:21 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:25 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 07[IKE] sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:25 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 07[NET] sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: nm-l2tp[5561] <warn>  Timeout trying to establish IPsec connection
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: nm-l2tp[5561] <info>  Terminating ipsec script with PID 5634.
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: nm-l2tp[5561] <warn>  Could not establish IPsec tunnel.
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 14[CFG] rereading secrets
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 14[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: (nm-l2tp-service:5561): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1492068331.6006] vpn-connection[0x1db45c0,83adbec9-817f-4faf-9839-42eb41897c10,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1492068331.6023] vpn-connection[0x1db45c0,83adbec9-817f-4faf-9839-42eb41897c10,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state change reason: unknown (0)
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1492068331.6067] vpn-connection[0x1db45c0,83adbec9-817f-4faf-9839-42eb41897c10,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN service disappeared
Apr 13 12:55:31 pratip-vostro-2520 NetworkManager[858]: <warn>  [1492068331.6102] vpn-connection[0x1db45c0,83adbec9-817f-4faf-9839-42eb41897c10,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
Apr 13 12:55:32 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 05[IKE] sending retransmit 2 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Apr 13 12:55:32 pratip-vostro-2520 charon: 05[NET] sending packet: from 10.17.144.110[500] to 76.194.82.189[500] (248 bytes)
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to connect to? I can see you're using secrets to authenticate, and also certificates... so which is it? also - the log you posted only shows the first part of the connection made by the daemon. and can you add the following line to your /etc/ipsec.conf file please: "charondebug = [dmn 2, mgr 2, ike 2, job 2, cfg 2, knl 2, net 2, enc 2, lib 2, esp 2]" under "config setup" section? then post the charon log again

Comment: I am trying to connect a VPN server, credential provided by client with pre-shared key value.

Comment: First of all, I think you should read this: https://askubuntu.com/help/asking regarding the form of asking questions in this site.

Comment: Second, your logs are still only partial, and provide very little information. from your log you can see that you can't pass the "first stage" of and IKE connection, so you won't be able to establish an IPsec connection. The first thing you need to do is check the routing between the two points that make the IPsec NAT

Comment: After you're done with that, and you have your routing set correctly - you can proceed to the "next stage". If you can't establish a connection on that stage, try and check your secrets - maybe they don't match.

Comment: Also - you're looking at one end of the connection. It seems that this end is providing the "I don't know why it got disconnected" answer - try and set the same line in the config file at the other end, and check the other end of the connection

Answer (score 18):

I found the solution in developer's repository.

https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/issues/38#issuecomment-303052751

Version 1.2.6 no longer overrides the default IPsec ciphers and I suspect your VPN server is using a legacy cipher newer strongSwan versions consider to be broken.

See the user specified IPsec cipher suites section in the README.md file on how to supplement the strongSwan default ciphers with your own :

https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp#user-specified-ipsec-ikev1-cipher-suites

I would recommend installing the ike-scan package to check what ciphers your VPN server is advertising it supports, e.g. :

```
$ sudo systemctl stop strongswan  
$ sudo ike-scan 123.54.76.9  
Starting ike-scan 1.9 with 1 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/ike-scan/)
123.54.76.9   Main Mode Handshake returned HDR=(CKY-R=5735eb949670e5dd) SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=2:modp1024 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
Ending ike-scan 1.9: 1 hosts scanned in 0.263 seconds (3.80 hosts/sec).  1 returned handshake; 0 returned notify
```

So with this example where a broken 3DES cipher is advertised, in the advanced section of the IPsec dialog box for version 1.2.6, add the following:

- Phase1 Algorithms : 3des-sha1-modp1024
- Phase2 Algorithms : 3des-sha1

*After all steps try you L2TP connnection, it must be established.*

Comment: Thanks. It worked by adding Phase1 and Phase 2 Algorithms !!

Comment: As per a comment further down in that link I also had to disable xl2tpd with `sudo systemctl stop xl2tpd` (https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/issues/38#issuecomment-303089948)